# How to remove files from several locations with similar paths but not identical paths

Tags: powershell, delete-file

I'm trying to come up with a way in order to quickly remove multiple files that are in similar child directories. I need to accomplish the removals quickly to several domain controllers so they don't replicate and replace the deleted files.

The file paths vary slightly but enough and I was hoping to use wildcards (*) to cut down the six possible path variations to only two.

something along these lines:
The {} actually exist since they are hash values

```
C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain\Policies\{*}\User*\Script\Logon\abc*
C:\Windows\SYSVOL\sysvol\xxxx\Policies\{*}\User*\Script\Logon\abc*
```

Initially I was thinking along the lines of using a recursive select-string search and pipe it to remove-item but I was getting an access denial error when i was just hypothesizing the search without the pipe to remove-item.

```
gci -path C:\Windows\SYSVOL\ -rec | select-string -pattern "domain\Policies\{*}\User*\Script\Logon\abc*
```

and

```
gci -path C:\Windows\SYSVOL\ -rec | select-string -pattern "sysvol\xxxx\Policies\{*}\User*\Script\Logon\abc*" | remove-item $_
```

(the remove-item is basically pseudo code)

I tried delimiting the {'s and 's but that didn't work either.

Once I have this working in theory I would then need to use the invoke-command to try to get this removal process to work its way through the list of systems that need this operation.

I don't know if this is the right approach / best approach, or if it is even doable.
Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: for clarification, there actually is a back slash in between "Policies" and the { bracket. The editor removed them when I posted it.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You're looking to remove all files in a directory called `abc`, in both locations? `Remove-Item -LiteralPath` accepts multiple paths so all you would need to do is pass it both.

Comment: no, just a single file in those directories, not the entire directory contents.

can you give me an example with the Literal Path? 

thanks